# A class in a jar in my classpath cannot be instantiated by ant while reverse engineering in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, log4j, slf4j

I have an archived program that I have taken out of mothballs.  After upgrading to Java 8 I had to make some changes that it required and now I am having a problem with loading a class from a jar on which I have a dependency.

My ant file:

```
    <property name="source.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="build" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="../javautil-lib" />
    <property name="etc.dir" value="etc" />
    <property name="classes.dir" value="target/classes" />
    <property name="gensource.dir" value="${build.dir}/src" />

    <property name="hbm.pkg.name" value="org.javautil.${schema.packageName}" />
    <property name="hbm.cfg.file" value="${etc.dir}/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="hbm.rev.file" value="${etc.dir}/hibernate.reveng.xml" />

    <property name="hibernate.properties" value="${etc.dir}/hibernate.properties" />

    <path id="class.path">
        <pathelement location="${classes.dir}" />
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                        <include name="log4j-api-2.7.jar" />
                        <include name="log4j-core-2.7.jar" />
            <include name="commons-collections-3.2.1.jar" />
                        <include name="dom4j-1.6.1.jar" />
                        <include name="freemarker-2.3.14.jar" />
                        <include name="h2-1.3.159.jar" />
                        <include name="hibernate-3.3.1.jar" />
                        <include name="hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar" />
                        <include name="ojdbc6_11_1.jar" />
                        <include name="slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${gensource.dir}" />
    </target>

    <property name="class.path.string" refid="class.path" />

    <target name="all" depends="compile-strategy,generateHBM,generateCode"/>

    <target name="compile-strategy" depends="init">
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="." destdir="${classes.dir}" debug="true" debugLevel="lines,vars,source">
            <include name="${reveng.strategy.file}" />
            <classpath refid="classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <taskdef name="hibernatetool" classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask" classpathref="class.path" />

    <target name="clean" description="remove hibernate generated files">
        <delete dir="${gensource.dir}" failonerror="false" />
        <mkdir dir="${gensource.dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- todo reuse the other two tasks -->
    <target name="generateCode" description="generate hibernate pojos" depends="clean">

        <echo level="info">"generate code:" using classpath: ${class.path.string}</echo>


        <hibernatetool destdir="${gensource.dir}" classpath="${class.path.string}">
            <jdbcconfiguration configurationfile="${hbm.cfg.file}" packagename="${hbm.pkg.name}" revengfile="${hbm.rev.file}" 
                reversestrategy="${RevEngStrategyClass}" />
            <hbm2hbmxml />

        </hibernatetool>


        <hibernatetool destdir="${gensource.dir}" classpath="${class.path.string}">
            <jdbcconfiguration configurationfile="${hbm.cfg.file}" packagename="${hbm.pkg.name}" revengfile="${hbm.rev.file}" 
                reversestrategy="${RevEngStrategyClass}" />
            <hbm2java jdk5="true" />
        </hibernatetool>
    </target>

    <target name="generateHBM" description="generate hibernate mapping files">

        <echo level="info">using classpath: ${class.path.string}</echo>
        <hibernatetool destdir="${gensource.dir}" classpath="${class.path.string}">
            <jdbcconfiguration configurationfile="${hbm.cfg.file}" packagename="${hbm.pkg.name}" revengfile="${hbm.rev.file}"
                reversestrategy="${RevEngStrategyClass}" />
            <hbm2hbmxml />

        </hibernatetool>
    </target>

    <target name="generateHibernatePojosFromJdbcMeta" description="generate hibernate pojos from hbm files">
        <echo level="info">using classpath: ${class.path.string}</echo>
        <hibernatetool destdir="${gensource.dir}" classpath="${class.path.string}">
            <jdbcconfiguration configurationfile="${hbm.cfg.file}" packagename="${hbm.pkg.name}" revengfile="${hbm.rev.file}"
                reversestrategy="${RevEngStrategyClass}" />
            <hbm2hbmxml />
        </hibernatetool>
    </target>



    <target name="generateHibernatePojos" description="generate hibernate pojos from hbm files">
        <echo level="info">using classpath: ${class.path.string}</echo>
        <hibernatetool destdir="${gensource.dir}" classpath="${class.path.string}">
            <configuration>
                <fileset dir="${gensource.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*.hbm.xml" />
                </fileset>
            </configuration>

            <hbm2java jdk5="true" ejb3="true" />
        </hibernatetool>
    </target>


    <target name="generateSchema" description="generate schema from hbm files">
        <taskdef name="schemaexport" classname="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExportTask" classpathref="class.path" />
        <schemaexport properties="${hibernate.properties}" quiet="no" text="yes" drop="no" delimiter=";" output="generated-schema.sql">
            <fileset dir="${gensource.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.hbm.xml" />
            </fileset>
        </schemaexport>
    </target>
</project>
```

The output from `ant -debug -logfile /tmp/ant.output`

```
Adding reference: ant.PropertyHelper
Detected Java version: 1.8 in: /opt/jdk1.8.0_111/jre
Detected OS: Linux
Adding reference: ant.ComponentHelper
Setting ro project property: ant.file -> /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/distributor-reporting/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type -> file
Adding reference: ant.projectHelper
Adding reference: ant.parsing.context
Adding reference: ant.targets
parsing buildfile /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/distributor-reporting/build.xml with URI = file:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/distributor-reporting/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.project.name -> build-tasks
Adding reference: build-tasks
Setting ro project property: ant.project.default-target -> all
Setting ro project property: ant.file.build-tasks -> /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/distributor-reporting/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type.build-tasks -> file
Project base dir set to: /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/distributor-reporting
 +Target: 
 +Target: init
 +Target: all
 +Target: compile-strategy
 +Target: clean
 +Target: generateCode
 +Target: generateHBM
 +Target: generateHibernatePojosFromJdbcMeta
 +Target: generateHibernatePojos
 +Target: generateSchema
Adding reference: ant.LocalProperties
parsing buildfile jar:file:/usr/share/java/ant/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/usr/share/java/ant/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
Property "RevEngStrategyClass" has not been set
Setting project property: reveng.strategy.file -> ${RevEngStrategyClass}.java
Setting project property: schema.packageName -> sales
Setting project property: RevEngStrategyClass -> com.caribbeandataservices.vendreporting.hibernate.RevEngStrategy
Setting project property: source.dir -> src
Setting project property: build.dir -> build
Setting project property: lib.dir -> ../javautil-lib
Setting project property: etc.dir -> etc
Setting project property: classes.dir -> target/classes
Setting project property: gensource.dir -> build/src
Setting project property: hbm.pkg.name -> org.javautil.sales
Setting project property: hbm.cfg.file -> etc/hibernate.cfg.xml
Setting project property: hbm.rev.file -> etc/hibernate.reveng.xml
Setting project property: hibernate.properties -> etc/hibernate.properties
Adding reference: class.path
fileset: Setup scanner in dir /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib with patternSet{ includes: [log4j-api-2.7.jar, log4j-core-2.7.jar, commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, dom4j-1.6.1.jar, freemarker-2.3.14.jar, h2-1.3.159.jar, hibernate-3.3.1.jar, hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar, ojdbc6_11_1.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar] excludes: [] }
Setting project property: class.path.string -> /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/distributor-reporting/target/classes:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/freemarker-2.3.14.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/h2-1.3.159.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-3.3.1.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/log4j-api-2.7.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/log4j-core-2.7.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/ojdbc6_11_1.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/ant/HibernateToolTask.class
Class org.apache.tools.ant.Task loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.Object loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.Throwable loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.RuntimeException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.ClassLoader loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.util.Map loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.util.List loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.ant.ExporterTask
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/ant/ExporterTask.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.ant.ExporterTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DAOExporterTask
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/ant/Hbm2DAOExporterTask.class
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2JavaExporterTask
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/ant/Hbm2JavaExporterTask.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2JavaExporterTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DAOExporterTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DocExporterTask
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/ant/Hbm2DocExporterTask.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DocExporterTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2HbmXmlExporterTask
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/ant/Hbm2HbmXmlExporterTask.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2HbmXmlExporterTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2CfgXmlExporterTask
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/ant/Hbm2CfgXmlExporterTask.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2CfgXmlExporterTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.ant.GenericExporterTask
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/ant/GenericExporterTask.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.ant.GenericExporterTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DDLExporterTask
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/ant/Hbm2DDLExporterTask.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DDLExporterTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.ant.ConfigurationTask
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/ant/ConfigurationTask.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.ant.ConfigurationTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.ant.JPAConfigurationTask
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/ant/JPAConfigurationTask.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.ant.JPAConfigurationTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.ant.AnnotationConfigurationTask
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/ant/AnnotationConfigurationTask.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.ant.AnnotationConfigurationTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.ant.JDBCConfigurationTask
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/ant/JDBCConfigurationTask.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.ant.JDBCConfigurationTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
 +Datatype hibernatetool org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask
Setting ro project property: ant.project.invoked-targets -> all
Attempting to create object of type org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor
Adding reference: ant.executor
Build sequence for target(s) `all' is [init, compile-strategy, generateHBM, clean, generateCode, all]
Complete build sequence is [init, compile-strategy, generateHBM, clean, generateCode, all, generateHibernatePojosFromJdbcMeta, generateSchema, generateHibernatePojos, ]

init:
    [mkdir] Skipping /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/distributor-reporting/target/classes because it already exists.
    [mkdir] Skipping /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/distributor-reporting/build/src because it already exists.

compile-strategy:
fileset: Setup scanner in dir /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/distributor-reporting with patternSet{ includes: [${RevEngStrategyClass}.java] excludes: [] }
    [javac] No sources found.

generateHBM:
     [echo] using classpath: /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/distributor-reporting/target/classes:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/freemarker-2.3.14.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/h2-1.3.159.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-3.3.1.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/log4j-api-2.7.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/log4j-core-2.7.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/ojdbc6_11_1.jar:/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
Class java.util.ArrayList loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.util.Properties loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.tools.ant.types.PropertySet loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.tools.ant.types.Path loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.ant.QueryExporterTask
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/ant/QueryExporterTask.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.ant.QueryExporterTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.ant.HbmLintExporterTask
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/ant/HbmLintExporterTask.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.ant.HbmLintExporterTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.io.File loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-3.3.1.jar org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.class
Class java.io.Serializable loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.tools.ant.types.Environment$Variable loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.io.IOException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.io.FileNotFoundException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.io.InputStream loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.io.FileInputStream loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.HibernateException
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-3.3.1.jar org/hibernate/HibernateException.class
Finding class org.hibernate.exception.NestableRuntimeException
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-3.3.1.jar org/hibernate/exception/NestableRuntimeException.class
Finding class org.hibernate.exception.Nestable
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-3.3.1.jar org/hibernate/exception/Nestable.class
Class org.hibernate.exception.Nestable loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class org.hibernate.exception.NestableRuntimeException loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class org.hibernate.HibernateException loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.Exception loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.NoSuchMethodException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCMetaDataConfiguration
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/cfg/JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.class
Class org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCMetaDataConfiguration loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.ReverseEngineeringStrategy
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/cfg/reveng/ReverseEngineeringStrategy.class
Class org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.ReverseEngineeringStrategy loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.DefaultReverseEngineeringStrategy
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/cfg/reveng/DefaultReverseEngineeringStrategy.class
Class org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.DefaultReverseEngineeringStrategy loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.String loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.Exporter
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/hbm2x/Exporter.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.Exporter loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.StringBuffer loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
[hibernatetool] Executing Hibernate Tool with a JDBC Configuration (for reverse engineering)
Class java.util.Iterator loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.tools.ant.Project loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.Class loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
[hibernatetool] 1. task: hbm2hbmxml (Generates a set of hbm.xml files)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.HibernateMappingExporter
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/hbm2x/HibernateMappingExporter.class
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.GenericExporter
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/hbm2x/GenericExporter.class
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/hbm2x/AbstractExporter.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.GenericExporter loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.HibernateMappingExporter loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.ExporterException
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/hbm2x/ExporterException.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.ExporterException loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.util.HashMap loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.GenericExporter$1
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/hbm2x/GenericExporter$1.class
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.GenericExporter$ModelIterator
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/hbm2x/GenericExporter$ModelIterator.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.GenericExporter$ModelIterator loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.GenericExporter$1 loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.GenericExporter$2
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/hibernate-tools-1.3.159.jar org/hibernate/tool/hbm2x/GenericExporter$2.class
Class org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.GenericExporter$2 loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)

ommitted for briefness

Finding class freemarker.log.Logger
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/freemarker-2.3.14.jar freemarker/log/Logger.class
Class freemarker.log.Logger loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.IllegalAccessError loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.InstantiationError loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class freemarker.log.LoggerFactory
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/freemarker-2.3.14.jar freemarker/log/LoggerFactory.class
Class freemarker.log.LoggerFactory loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class freemarker.template.utility.ClassUtil
Loaded from /common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/javautil-lib/freemarker-2.3.14.jar freemarker/template/utility/ClassUtil.class
Class freemarker.template.utility.ClassUtil loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.log4j.Logger loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.log4j.Logger loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)

BUILD FAILED
/common/home/jjs/workspace-javautil/distributor-reporting/build.xml:83: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at freemarker.template.utility.ClassUtil.forName(ClassUtil.java:77)
    at freemarker.log.Logger.createFactory(Logger.java:297)
    at freemarker.log.Logger.createFactory(Logger.java:272)
    at freemarker.log.Logger.selectLoggerLibrary(Logger.java:134)
    at freemarker.log.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:237)
    at freemarker.template.utility.SecurityUtilities.<clinit>(SecurityUtilities.java:67)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.<clinit>(BeansWrapper.java:147)
    at freemarker.template.WrappingTemplateModel.<clinit>(WrappingTemplateModel.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.TemplateHelper.init(TemplateHelper.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.setupTemplates(AbstractExporter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.start(AbstractExporter.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.tool.ant.ExporterTask.execute(ExporterTask.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.execute(HibernateToolTask.java:186)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:853)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.message.Message
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 31 more

Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug.  It works in 1.8.3 but not 1.97

A bug report has been filed.

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60365